# ¿Cómo retornar la entidad completa en vez de solo su ID?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una entidad patinadores, que tienen el id de una escuela a la que pertenecen, entonces, cuando hago un GET a patinadores, el json retorna esto:

```
{"id":2,"nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Perez","fechaNac":"2012-07-04","direccion":"Alguna","esc_id":1,"created_at":"2020-07-04T11:14:58.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-07-04T11:14:59.000000Z"}]
```

pero yo quiero que en vez del id me retorne todos los datos de la escuela, es posible? como puedo lograrlo?

les dejo el código por si les sirve:
rutas

```
Route::resource('patinadores', 'PatinadorController');
Route::resource('escuelas', 'EscuelaController');
```

models

Modelo Escuela

```
class escuela extends Model
{
    public $table = "escuelas";
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'descripcion'];
}
```

Modelo Patinador

```
class Patinador extends Model
{
    public $table = "table_patinadores";
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'apellido','fechaNac', 'direccion'];

    public function escuela(){
    return $this->hasOne('escuela');
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega cómo estas haciendo la consulta y devolviendo los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tus modelos estan incompletos, pues al modelo `Escuela` le falta la relación [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
- Idealmente nombra a los modelos si en singular, pero también la primer letra en mayúscula
- Puedes hacer uso de [eagger loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) para cargar al modelo `Patinador` y sus relaciones o relación asociada en este caso
- En tu sistema de rutas no hagas 2 declaraciones de tipo *resource*, perfecto puedes usar solo una y pasarle como array asociativo ambas [resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Entonces tu ruta puede quedar así:

```
Route::resources(['patinadores' => 'PatinadorController', 'escuelas' => 'EscuelaController']);
```

La relación en el modelo `Escuela`

```
class escuela extends Model
{
    public $table = "escuelas";
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'descripcion'];

    public function patinador()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patinador::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora a nivel de la consulta:

```
$consulta = Patinador::with('escuela')->findOrFail($idPatinador);
```

Answer (score 0):

En el GET a patinadores, probablemente estés devolviendo algo como:

```
return Patinador::all();
```

Tienes que indicar la relación adecuada para que la cargue al devolverla, de esta forma:

```
return Patinador::with('escuela')->get();
```

De esta forma, podrás ver que en el json aparece un nuevo atributo escuela asociado a cada patinador con los datos de la escuela que le corresponden.

En el siguiente link puedes encontrar más información sobre eager loading:

[Eloquent Eelationships - Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)